# Chrome Developer Device Mode Cropped Window

Tags: google-chrome, debugging

I am running Chrome 65 and since the last upgrade whenever I try and activate the device mode in developer tools (i.e. to see how the page would look like on a mobile phone), only the top left quadrant of the window is displayed correctly. The remaining 75% of the screen is left white (but very strangely accepts input)

Comment: I'm having the same *$€£ issue... Please update your ticket as soon as you've found a solution...

Comment: https://crbug.com/819489

Comment: This previously reported bug in Chrome has been fixed in Build 66 (I just upgraded and problem has gone away) and also in the latest patches released for Build 65.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was experiencing the same issue in Chrome 65. Today, I saw that there was a pending update in Chrome. I installed this update and noted that the issue was gone.

The new update has the following version number (at least on my machine): 65.0.3325.162

Comment: binici.. when you got enough rep... post this as comment to OP's question and remove this as answer. Thanks! BTW... finish [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) the tour and you'll understand my comment.

Comment: This is apparently a known Chromium bug on Mac only, that originated in Chrome version 65 and has been subsequently fixed in Chrome version 65 build 150 for more details see: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=819489#c63

Comment: I just tried upgrading my Mac which is still OS Sierra and I could not get past build 124 for Chrome 65, whereas you need build 162 to get the fix. Any ideas?

Comment: By the way I meant patch 162 not build 162